# Trying to create calculated column for YTD values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I need to calculate a YTD value each day based on a budget table. My table looks like this:

```
Month     Rev-50100   Rev-50101
1/31/19   75000.00    364.27
2/28/19   76000.00    360.57
3/31/19   82000.00    391.58
```

I'm able to handle the MTD pretty easily with a "PerDay" column that takes the monthly value and divides by the number of days in that month, then multiply the PerDay value based on the day of the month.

For YTD, I would need to add each previous month, then a MTD value for the current month. So on March 2nd my expected outcome is (75000+76000+ ((82000/31)*2)) = 156,290.32

I have been trying to use a combination of RunningValue and my MTD calculation, but RunningValue is adding in the entire current month, and not letting me get YTD value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, I may have a solution for you.  You need each month from the `Rev-50100` column, except the last value and add the `MTD` value instead.

To solve this, you can use the `Last` function to remove the last value from the `RunningValue` and then add `MTD`.

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Rev-50100.Value, Sum, Nothing) 
 - Last(Fields!Rev-50100.Value, Nothing) 
 + ReportItems!MtdTextbox.Value
```